# DataGridView losing DataSource after Window Losing Focus

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Complete Odd Ball this one. Could be something simple but it has me stumped.

I have a DataGridView implemented on say FormA. The DataGrid has a DataSource which is a Table from a DataSet.

I have a column in DGV that is a button that launches another form call this FormB. Data from FormB is then pushed to Variables and then after FormB is closed a timer Fires on FormA which then checks if there is new data to Update to the Row that the button belonged to.

Values from specific columns are then updated in DGV accordingly.

This all works completely fine Until FormA isn't the Applications Launch Form. If I put a FormC in place which acts as a login and then on successful login launches FormA before Closing itself, everything works fine until after I click the button in the Column of the DGV. Once FormB then launches this time the DataSource for DGV is set to nothing and this time when the timer Fires I get a Index out of bounds error (which would be expected since my DGV now has 0 rows and 0 columns!). It's like as if FormA can't reference it's own DataGridView anymore even though that form hasn't been closed.

Not sure what code to provide but happy to share what part you think could be the issue.

Comment: On which form and in what event is the DataGridView filled?

Comment: I do not get the purpose of the timer.

Comment: You're probably trying to use the default instance of `FormA` to access controls  child of an already created instance of the Form.

Comment: Mary, FormA has the DataGrid and is filled after a function in another class has completed and provided there is more than 0 results in the Table the datasource for the DataGridView is set.


The Timer is only fired so that FormA knows that FormB has been finished with and it then checks to see if it has any new values that it needs to handle. FormB could be left open for an infinite amount of time, so it's better to let FormA know somehow that it should start handling user Input again.

Comment: Jimi - would you care to explain further, so I can maybe narrow down this possibility?

Comment: Adding some code would help. Start where you open FormA, and code for setting the data source of the DataGridView.